# Detect if user opened the View for the first Time In iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, view, nsuserdefaults

I know how I can detect if the application first time opened using NSUserDefault:

```
BOOL didRunBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"didRunBefore"];

     if (!didRunBefore) {
      //Your Launch Code
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"didRunBefore"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

       }
```

*The Issue: I want an Alert for ever view explaining about what features it contains and only open this alert when the app is first launched?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an OOP programmer you can make a common public method.

```
+ (BOOL)checkWhetherRunBefore:(NSString *)key
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:key];
} 

+ (void)hasRunForMyClass:(NSString *)key
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And in your ViewController , you can code in the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear like this :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    if(![HelpController checkWhetherRunBefore:NSStringFromClass([self class])])
    {
        //do your thing
        [HelpController hasRunForMyClass:NSStringFromClass([self class])]
    }

}
```

Comment: +1.  I like it, but as an objective-c oop programmer, you might consider a UIViewController category.  It would contain the same methods, but with NSStringFromClass(self) in place of the less-than-pretty 'key' parameter.

Comment: My view is Called "MainView" so how can I alert the user when the View is first opened.

Comment: @danh yes you are right , in the category is very good , or maybe can make a MyBaseViewController : UIViewController , and MyBaseViewController add some common properties and method , all my viewControllers all inherit MyBaseViewController

Comment: @iProgrammed when you add your MainView to its superView , you can use if(![HelpController checkWhetherRunBefore:NSStringFromClass([_mainView class])]) to check

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your code in  viewDidLoad

viewDidLoad will run only one time when app load your view. (except low memory)

Next time you load the view again in viewDidLoad, you can check bool didRunBefore

Answer (score 1):

You can use any key you want.

In `FirstViewController`:

```
BOOL didRunBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstViewController_didRunBefore"];

if (!didRunBefore) {
    //Your Launch Code
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstViewController_didRunBefore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In `SecondViewController`:

```
BOOL didRunBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SecondViewController_didRunBefore"];

if (!didRunBefore) {
    //Your Launch Code
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SecondViewController_didRunBefore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo have to need to detect application first launch, you can detect t like this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"])
  [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
You can then test for it later...

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
if([defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"])           
{
  // do something or not...
}
```